# How to change the file path in INDEX MATCH function to include a helper cell instead?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a master excel workbook where i some of my data are referenced from closed workbook. In cell B5 for eg, I have a formula as such:
`=INDEX('A:\\File\[File 1.xlsx\]File 10.07.2023'!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&$A5&"*",'A:\\File\[File 1.xlsx\]File 10.07.2023'!$C:$C,0))`

Path directory:  A:\File[File 1.xlsx]File 10.07.2023'
File 1.xlsx : closed reference workbook name
File 10.07.2023 : sheet name that is included in File 1.xlsx that i need to get my reference data from
A5 : cell that i match for from the master excel workbook to File 1.xlsx and get the corresponding column C data

I want the path directory to be referenced from a helper cell say for eg C5
the formula in C5: FileList!E7
the E7 cell formula: `=INDEX($A7:$A7,MATCH(MAX($C7:$C7),$C7:$C7,0))`
My A7 and C7 are my latest workbook path and date modified. Both are from power query

How do i replace the workbook path with the helper cell?

I tried this formula but keep getting #REF
`=INDEX(INDIRECT(C5& "!$A:$A"), MATCH("\*" & $A5 & "\*", INDIRECT(C5& "!$C:$C"), 0))`

even chatgpt cant solve my problem, anyone has any idea how to solve this?
I want to reference a closed workbook + VBA is not an option for me

Comment: INDIRECT will only work if the source file is open, so there's actually no real point in including the path